# Sliver Appbar con circle avatar a la mitad FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, app, dart

Cordial saludo colegas, estoy desarrollando una app movil en flutter y mi problema es el siguiente necesito un sliver appbar que se vea de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero aun no logro que el circulo quede asi, salido a la mitad. Tengo el siguiente codigo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomScrollViewComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomScrollViewComponentState createState() => _CustomScrollViewComponentState();
}

class _CustomScrollViewComponentState extends State<CustomScrollViewComponent> {
  Widget _createAppbar() {
    return SliverAppBar(
        elevation: 2.0,
        expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3,
        floating: false,
        pinned: true,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          background: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: FractionalOffset(0.0,0.6),
                        end: FractionalOffset(0.0,1.0),
                        colors: [
                          Color.fromRGBO(29, 75, 136, 1.0),
                          Color.fromRGBO(18, 57, 99, 1.0),
                        ]
                    )
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 150.0, // (background container size) - (circle height / 2)
                child: Container(
                  height: 100.0,
                  width: 100.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.green
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _createAppbar()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

El resultado de este codigo es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podria hacer para que quede salido a la mitad como el diseño inicial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de como implementarlo, básicamente el truco es usar un `Stack` y `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

```dart
class MySample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: MySliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 200),
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (_, index) => ListTile(
                  title: Text("Index: $index"),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySliverAppBar extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double expandedHeight;

  MySliverAppBar({@required this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Color(0XFF2E5596),
                Color(0XFF16304E),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: shrinkOffset / expandedHeight,
            child: Text(
              "MySliverAppBar",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                fontSize: 23,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: expandedHeight / 2 - shrinkOffset,
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.5,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: (1 - shrinkOffset / expandedHeight),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 3),
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: expandedHeight,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo que leas el post que escribí sobre como personalizar un `AppBar` y `SliverAppBar`

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-increase-the-power-of-your-appbar-sliverappbar-c4f67c4e076f

Comment: Gracias men, ya había leído el post cuando respondiste por el grupo, y lo intente así pero no quedaba como necesitaba, en este caso que replicas tu post con lo que necesito me funciono a la perfección, le hice unas modificaciones para usar un circle avatar, y quite lo de la lista porque solo necesito el appbar. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la respuesta de diegoveloper, hice la siguiente modificación al código de su respuesta, ya que yo solo necesito el appbar y usarlo con un circle avatar.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomScrollViewComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomScrollViewComponentState createState() => _CustomScrollViewComponentState();
}

class _CustomScrollViewComponentState extends State<CustomScrollViewComponent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Material(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: MySliverAppBar(expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.3),
              pinned: true,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySliverAppBar extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final double expandedHeight;

  MySliverAppBar({@required this.expandedHeight});

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      overflow: Overflow.visible,
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topCenter,
              end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              colors: [
                Color.fromRGBO(29, 75, 136, 1.0),
                Color.fromRGBO(18, 57, 99, 1.0)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: expandedHeight / 1.7 - shrinkOffset,
          left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 3.5,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4.3,
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4.6,
              backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://pm1.narvii.com/7219/b493e34427e645f3fb82d09f2185a177d9230392r1-466-658v2_00.jpg'),
            ),
          )
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => expandedHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => kToolbarHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

De esta forma queda de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]